# Use CSOM with Secret to integrate with sharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, azure, azure-functions, azure-active-directory

I found this video on YouTube which show how to use PnP core inside Azure Function to integrate with SharePoint Online @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9erhWdwbkq8&t=543s

but can i have the same features but instead of using PnP core to use CSOM + instead of securing the Azure Active Directory App using Certificate to secure it using client secret ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use a secret instead of a certificate?

Comment: @CallumCrowley thanks for the reply. because client secrets can provide an acceptable level of security with minimal cost/administration effort to manage it compared to certificates ... but from Ron answer seems if we want to use CSOM we need to use certificates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint Client Object Model and REST API require that you use client Id and certificate when requesting tokens that have application (app only) permissions from Azure AD. If you use a client Id and secret to get a token that has application permissions, the SharePoint Client Object Model and REST API will throw an exception when that token is used with a request.

It's worth noting that the Microsoft Graph doesn't have the same restriction. With Microsoft Graph you can use client Id and secret to get tokens that have application permissions and then use those tokens when making requests to SharePoint.

I'm not sure why CSOM and REST have the restriction and Microsoft Graph does not. It seems a little counterintuitive.

Comment: thanks for the reply... so if we want to use CSOM then we have to use certificates? and from where we can gain such a certificate? assuming we do not want to use self-signed because we are going to publish it to a production environment... second question, regarding Graph does it have a libraries we can use inside visual studio ? or we will need to perform row REST API calls ? Thanks

Comment: I'll answer each of your questions in a separate comment. First, if you want to use CSOM with a token that has application permissions then, yes, you will need to use client Id and certificate.

Comment: The use of self-signed certificates for Azure AD authentication is pretty common, but if you want you can get a certificate from a certificate authority like Let's Encrypt or DigiCert.

Comment: There are Microsoft Graph SDKs for C#, JavaScript, and other languages you can use if you'd prefer not to use the REST API.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview

Comment: so do you mean that CSOM is really an old school now? and we need to replace it with Graph? i hope that this is not the case as i spent many efforts in understanding it and there are plenty of documentation about it even on Microsoft itself without mentioning that it is been deprecated

Comment: second question, if CSOM is old (legacy)  approach since it uses SharePoint REST API, then is PNP libraries also considered as legacy since they are build on top of CSOM?

Comment: can you please advice on my above 2 comments?

Comment: No, you don't need to replace CSOM with Microsoft Graph right away, however there may come a time where you will need to do so. When that might happen depends on how quickly Microsoft can get Microsoft Graph close to functional parity with CSOM. They have a long way to go to do that, so I expect CSOM to be a viable choice for several years to come.

Answer (score 0):

Other people are saying that you need a certificate to work with CSOM app context permissions. Thats not true, you can authenticate and use it with only client id and secret.

```
AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
            ClientContext context = authManager.GetACSAppOnlyContext(Siteurl, clientId, clientSecret);

            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQueryRetry(2);
```

It works. I have been using it this way all the time

Comment: That technique is using the add-in security model. That is, it is authenticating against Azure Access Control Services (ACS), not Azure AD. 

From Granting access using SharePoint App-Only (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs), "For new tenants, apps using an ACS app-only access token is disabled by default. We recommend using the Azure AD app-only model which is modern and more secure."

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation